# Codename One generated iOS certificate on multiple projects

Tags: codenameone, apple-developer

It is possible to use a certificate generated using Codename One wizard on two different projects without having to generate a new one every time I change project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Generate the certificate once in your first project and then in your second project, go through the certificate wizard and when it asks if you want to generate new certificates, choose "no".  Once complete, you'll then have to reference your certificates manually in the iOS settings.

I have a number of POC projects that I'm developing right now in hopes of porting my Android app over to codenameone, and I'm reusing the same certificates for all of them.

Comment: Correct! 
I'll add that it's not just possible it's also the "best practice".

Comment: Thanks Shai.  It would be awesome if the settings screen gave you more information about best practices as you used it.  E.g. if you're setting up certificates and it asks if you want to overwrite, provide some context as to why you'd want to NOT overwrite.  It took me a few hours of fiddling around to get used to reusing existing certificates.

Comment: I agree we need to work on the UX of that wizard and some other aspects in the settings